# How do I run a curl command in python

Tags: python, curl

This is the command I am running in `bash`:

```
curl -d "username=xxxxxx" -d "password=xxxxx" <<address>> --insecure --silent
```

How can I run this using Python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python

Comment: http://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 0):

Try `Subprocess`:

```
import subprocess
# ...

subprocess.call(["curl -d \"username=xxxxxx\" -d \"password=xxxxx\" https://xxxxx.com/logreg/login/ --insecure --silent" , shell=True)
```

I did not try what I wrote, but the essential is here.

Check this page for more info : [Subprocess management](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't want to explicitly run `curl`, but you just want to get the same result.

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get('https://example.com', auth=('user', 'pass'), verify=False)
>>> print(r.status_code)
200
```